# XSD, attributes for sequence elements

Tags: xsd, attributes

How do I define attributes for sequence elements?
This is the current xsd part,

```
<xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="40"\>
  <xsd:element name="Dimension" type="xsd:string" form="qualified"\>
    <xsd:choice>
    <xsd:element name="DimensionDebit" type="xsd:string" form="qualified"\>
    <xsd:element name="DimensionCredit" type="xsd:string" form="qualified"\>
  </xsd:choice>
</xsd:sequence>
```

Dimension can have DimensionCredit or DimensionCredit element, and all of them have attributes Number and Label.

Like this

Dimension Number="2" Label="Ty:">248000
DimensionDebit Number="2" Label="Ty:">248000

Comment: Like this, previous did ot show properly...<Dimension Number="2" Label="Ty:">248000</Dimension>
<DimensionDebit Number="2" Label="Ty:">248000</DimensionDebit>